# Node Express can't connect back to ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, express

first question here.

I'm creating a api that connects a front (node, express and ajax) with a Python swagger api. The problem is that although I can send information to the api through ajax -> node -> api, when the api responds, it stops at node (api -> node -/-> ajax).

The code is:

Node(express) router with the post to the python API:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs')
const request = require('request');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    data = req.body

    request.post('http://localhost:8080/passengers', {
            json: data
        }, (error, res2, body) => {
        if (!error && res2.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body)
            res.send(body)
        }
    })


});

module.exports = router;
```

I can confirm that "console.log(body)" works

Now, this is the ajax part.

```
$(() => {

    $('#calculateResult').on('submit', () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: './passengers',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#calculateResult').serialize(),     
            //async: false,    
            success: function (response) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<span>'+response+'</span>'
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
        .done((response)=>document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<span>'+response+'</span>')
    })
})
```

I have tried with the async flag, but although it shows the result, the page refreshes and the result gets lost

Lastly, this is the server part of the application, in case that some configuration could be causing the problem.

```
const path = require('path'); //Lo utilizamos para rutas porteables
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Añadimos jquery al proyecto
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
//Lo añadimos para obtener datos del formulario en un formato util de manera inmediata
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); //Esto lo usariamos para parsear a json
//Añadimos nuestra direccion de la api a la hoja de rutas
app.use('/passengers', require('./routes/api/passengers'));
//Especificamos la carga de recursos estaticos
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//Empezamos a escuchar en el puerto indicado
app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log('Server is running on PORT:', PORT)
);
```

Comment: "the page refreshes and the result gets lost" — Then something must be refreshing the page. There isn't enough of the client-side code to tell what.

Comment: If you have a form in the UI and a submit button, make sure that you `return false` to ensure that the form does not get `POST`ed which will make the page refresh!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, since I was sending the data through a  it blocked the way for my ajax petition to come back.

To solve it, it was as easy as adding

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To the jquery function